# custome error page for HTTP 414 request uri is too long

Tags: iis, http, custom-errors

I am able to set custom error pages for application level errors with help of customErrors as well as HTTP errors with httpErrors. But none of it handles HTTP 414 error.

I have gone through the answer on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130935/how-to-produce-a-custom-error-response-for-414-uri-too-large) but I am not sure whether I haven't researched enough to handle custom error page for this.

Comment: For those suggesting edits here assumed that this question is about Jetty server but it's not. It's about IIS for which I had applied tags to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `414 URI Too Long` ([RFC 7231 6.5.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.12)) is an error caused by a malformed `/path?query` part of an URI in the very first line of an HTTP request, the server never sees any other headers including `Host:` header of the second line: it already responds right after it gets the too long URI, e.g.

```
-->   GET /imagine/this/was/a/.../too.long?request=url HTTP/1.1
<--   HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Long
<--   Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
<--   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Therefore, it's natural that you cannot configure custom `414` pages per site on any web server.

I thought this would be possible server-wide on IIS using global *IIS > Error Pages*, but based on a test it seems that the `414` error is fixed and cannot be modified at all. The only source article I could find was from Microsoft's retired KB content, [Error Message: HTTP 414 - Request - URI Too Long](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248061/error-message-http-414---request---uri-too-long):

> IIS checks the string length of the URI and does not service a request
> when the URI is longer than expected. This is by design.

However, this condition should be rare as you could easily prevent it from happening by:

- using `POST` instead of `GET` whenever there could be longer query data than [2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/4631831).
- be careful that any redirection won't cause a loop where the URL itself gets used as a prefix.

With these principles a user would never see the page, and the human readable custom error pages are merely for users: any software can use the error code from the very first response header line.

Comment: Right. This has come as a security vulnerability that is why I was going researching for this as much as possible since attacker could try any combinations. Thanks for detailed info about that KB content too

Comment: What's the security vulnerability here? If IIS blocks all of these fine giving the `414` error, there shouldn't be any security related worries.

Comment: The vulnerability came here as to remove that Server : Microsoft HTTP API/2.0 header from response.